# Array full of regex, match to string, return path

Tags: node.js, node-red

Still very much a beginner, Just editing to make a little more sense

Here is an example payload.

```
{
"Status":
    {
    "result":[
        {
            "LastUpdate":"2017-09-07 06:47:09",
            "Type":"2",
            "Value":"' s the inside temperature",
            "idx":"4"
        }
    ],
    "status":"OK",
    "title":"GetUserVariable"
    },
"Devices":
    {
        "28":
        {
            "rid":"28",
            "regex":"(the )?(AC|(Air( )?(Con)?(ditioner)?))( Power)?( )?$/i"
        },
        "71":
        {
            "rid":"71",
            "regex":"(the )?inside temp/i"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to filter the "Devices" array down to entires that match Status.result[0].Value.

I have the follow code working, but it is in working in reverse, it returns the matching string, not the filtered array, just not sure how to reverse it.

```
var devices = msg.payload.Devices;
var request = [ msg.payload.Status.result[0].Value ];

var matches = request.filter(function (text) {
    return devices.some(function (regex) {
        var realregex = new RegExp(regex, "i");
        return realregex.test(text);
    });
});

msg = { topic:"Inputs", payload: { devices:devices, request:request } };

msg2 = { topic:"Output", payload: { matches:matches } };

return [ [ msg, msg2 ] ];
```

Thanks,
Wob

Comment: It's not totally clear what your asking here. It may help if you show some of the code you have already tried.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think I have myself confused. I have tried to clarify above, let me know if that is any clearer.

Comment: OK, so what have you already tried, show us that code as well so we can tell you what's wrong with it

Comment: I've posted one example I have tried, most of the examples I used returned the same type of "not a function" error.

Comment: I have made "some" progress, I have re-edited my post, hopefully it makes a little more sense.